# PyQt6 GUI - Interactive Brightness/Contrast Filter Creation

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, filter, interactive, pyqt6

Using PyQt6, the goal of my current GUI is to let the user add .bmp images to a listbox (taken from somewhere on their computer) and everytime the user clicks on an item in the listbox, that same image will appear twice in a QLabel (when I say twice, I mean there is the 'original' top image within a QLabel that should not change and then there's the alternate image in the bottom QLabel that will be manipulated by the user).

I want the the user to use a keypressevent ('W' or 'w') on the keyboard to increase brightness of ONLY the bottom image or a keypressevent ('S' or 's') on the keyboard to decrease brightness of ONLY the bottom image.

So, far I have everything up to the point where the user can find a folder on their computer, add .bmp images to the listbox, and have those images populate the top/bottom image QLabels. That's all done, the only thing I just cannot figure out is the way to make brightness filter interactive based on the user clicking the W or S keys on their keyboard.

Any suggestions for this?

[This is how the GUI looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrEg5.png)

**Full Code so far:**

```
import os
import sys

import pyautogui
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import qimage2ndarray

from PyQt6.QtGui import QPalette, QColor, QPixmap, QFont, QTransform, QImage
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QListWidget, \
QPushButton, QFileDialog, QLabel, QSizePolicy, QScrollArea, QSlider

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen_width, self.screen_height = pyautogui.size()

        self.setWindowTitle("GUI")
    
        main_frame_widget = QWidget()
        main_frame = QGridLayout()
        self.list_box = QListWidget()
        list_box_widget = QWidget(main_frame_widget)
    
        self.top_image = QLabel()
        top_image_text = QLabel(self.top_image)
    
        self.bottom_image = QLabel()
        bottom_image_text = QLabel(self.bottom_image)
    
        top_image_text.setText("Original Image")
        top_image_text.setFont(QFont("Arial", 26))
        top_image_text.setStyleSheet("border: none;")
    
        self.top_image.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid black;")
        self.top_image.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
    
        bottom_image_text.setText("Alternate Image")
        bottom_image_text.setFont(QFont("Arial", 26))
        bottom_image_text.setStyleSheet("border: none;")
    
        self.bottom_image.setStyleSheet("border: 2px solid black;")
        self.bottom_image.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
    
        main_frame.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        main_frame.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
        main_frame.setRowStretch(0, 1)
        main_frame.setRowStretch(1, 1)
    
        # Create a button to add items to the QListWidget
        list_box_add_items_button = QPushButton("Add Images")
        list_box_add_items_button.clicked.connect(self.add_folder)
    
        list_box_clear_all_button = QPushButton("Clear All Items")
        list_box_clear_all_button.clicked.connect(self.clear_list_box)
    
        list_box_clear_item_button = QPushButton("Clear An Item")
        list_box_clear_item_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_item_in_list_box)
    
        self.list_box.currentRowChanged.connect(self.on_item_clicked)
    
        # Create a vertical layout to add the QListWidget and button
        list_box_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        list_box_layout.addWidget(list_box_add_items_button)
        list_box_layout.addWidget(list_box_clear_all_button)
        list_box_layout.addWidget(list_box_clear_item_button)
        list_box_layout.addWidget(self.list_box)
    
        list_box_widget.setLayout(list_box_layout)
    
        main_frame.addWidget(self.top_image, 0, 0)
        main_frame.addWidget(self.bottom_image, 1, 0)
        main_frame.addWidget(list_box_widget, 1, 1)
    
        main_frame_widget.setLayout(main_frame)
    
        self.setCentralWidget(main_frame_widget)
    
    def on_item_clicked(self):
        if self.list_box.currentItem() is None:
            return
    
        image_path = self.list_box.currentItem().data(Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole)
        pixmap = QPixmap(image_path)
    
        scaled_pixmap_top = pixmap.scaled(self.top_image.contentsRect().width(), self.top_image.contentsRect().height(), Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.scaled_pixmap_bottom = pixmap.scaled(self.bottom_image.contentsRect().width(), self.bottom_image.contentsRect().height(), Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio)
    
        #Work in progress for contrast
        scaled_pixmap_bottom_to_q_image = self.scaled_pixmap_bottom.toImage()
    
        scaled_pixmap_bottom_image_to_ndarray = scaled_pixmap_bottom_to_q_image.bits().asstring(
            scaled_pixmap_bottom_to_q_image.width() * scaled_pixmap_bottom_to_q_image.height() * 4)
    
        self.final_ndarray = np.frombuffer(scaled_pixmap_bottom_image_to_ndarray, dtype=np.uint8).reshape(
            (scaled_pixmap_bottom_to_q_image.height(), scaled_pixmap_bottom_to_q_image.width(), 4))
    
        self.top_image.setPixmap(scaled_pixmap_top)
        self.bottom_image.setPixmap(self.scaled_pixmap_bottom)
    
    
    def clear_list_box(self):
        self.list_box.clear()
        self.top_image.clear()
        self.bottom_image.clear()
    
    
    def delete_item_in_list_box(self):
        current_item = self.list_box.currentItem()
        if current_item is not None:
            self.list_box.takeItem(self.list_box.row(current_item))
            if self.list_box.count() == 0:
                self.top_image.clear()
                self.bottom_image.clear()
    
    
    def add_folder(self):
        # Prompt the user to select a folder and add it to the list box
        folder_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Folder To Add To The ListBox")  # folder_path type is str
        if folder_path:
            bmp_files = []
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
                for file in files:
                    if file.endswith('.bmp'):
                        file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                        if os.path.basename(file_path) not in [os.path.basename(self.list_box.item(i).text()) for i in
                                                               range(self.list_box.count())]:
                            bmp_files.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root, file)))
    
                # Add the .bmp files to the list box
            for bmp_file in bmp_files:
                self.list_box.addItem(bmp_file)
    
    
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Shift:
            contrast_factor = 15
            converted = cv.convertScaleAbs(self.final_ndarray, alpha=contrast_factor, beta=0)
            qimage = qimage2ndarray.array2qimage(converted)
            pixmap = QPixmap(qimage)
            self.bottom_image.setPixmap(pixmap)
    
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_S:
            pass
            # self.scaled_pixmap_bottom -= self.change_contrast(self.scaled_pixmap_bottom)
    
            # self.bottom_image.setPixmap(self.scaled_pixmap_bottom)
    
        elif event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Escape:
            print("You have exited the code")
            sys.exit(1)
    
        else:
            print("Wrong button, please press 'W' to increase contrast or 'S' to decrease contrast")

app = QApplication([])  # pass in sys.argv if you want to use CLI arguments
window = MainWindow()
window.showMaximized()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

---

**What I'm Thinking:**

So, in my on_item_clicked function, I am taking the file name string (image_path) and converting it into a QPixmap so that I can eventually put it into my QLabel (self.bottom_image). Then I'm doing some scaling on it so that it matches my QLabel box sizes.

Now, my problem is that I don't know how to adjust brightness on a QPixmap object or if that's even possible or do I have to convert the QPixmap to an ndarray or integer? I tried converting the QPixmap to an ndarray and you'll see that in (self.final_ndarray), so now I'm trying to use that self.final_ndarray variable in my keyPressEvent function.

I mentioned earlier that eventually I want to use the 'W' or 'w' key presses to increase brightness, but for right now, I'm just trying to use the 'shift' key for testing. Everytime I click on the 'shift' key, my entire code just crashes and it doesn't give any kind of error that I see.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!